# Making several applications inside of an express app

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, express, routes

I come from a django background, and basically, the framework allows for a lot of modular code. I've created a simple blog engine in nodejs and express. However, all the routes end up being in my main `app.js` file, or rather `app.coffee`, since I used coffeescript for my nodejs applications, which complied to javascript.

So, say this is how my routes look:

```
app.get('/', index.index)
app.get('/users', user.list)
app.get('/blog', blog.blogList)
app.get('/blog/:id(\\d{5})', blog.blogEntry)
```

Now, the problem here is that if I want to sort these by categories, then this happens, then I would have to add another `app.get` function to the same file. Code:

```
app.get('/blog/categores/:cat(\w+), blog.someotherview)
```

If I wanted to add sorting according to time, for example:

```
app.get('/blog/time/:year(\\d{4}), blog.someYearView)
```

What I would like to do is delegate everything concerning `/blog` to be handled by `blog.js` for example. Ideally, how do I get all these routes out of the main `app.js` file?

You could easily do this by using the `include()` method in django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Express app in your `app.js` file, as you are used to. Then, do the same in the `blog.js` file. Import and use it within `app.js` as follows:

```
var blog = require('./blog');

var app = express();
app.use(blog);
```

Inside your `blog.js` file, all you need to do is to export your app:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/blog/...', ...);

module.exports = app;
```

To put it in other words: Any Express app can be used as middleware for any other Express app, hence you can create sub-apps.

Hope this helps.

PS: TJ Holowaychuk (the creator of Express) created a video on this, [Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](http://vimeo.com/56166857).